# How to display date in '12JAN2015 ' format from current date in mvc 4

Tags: c#, date

I need to display the date in  '12JAN2015 ' format if current date is 12th January 2015 in mvc 4 .Is it possible?

Comment: What did you tried? Try this [DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=false)]
 public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }

Comment: A little bit of googling would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0:ddMMMyyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```